# Adding fields to shopping cart items

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

I'm using Ubercart with Drupal and I was wondering if I can add more details in order / shopping cart views

In particular I need to add additional fields (beside title, price, etc) to each item in the shopping cart.

These fields would be CCK fields from the products content type.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should theme your product content type. For cart use themer of cart, see theme folder in ubercart, there's you can find files for theming, copy to own theme and change it (use print_r or devel module for investigating objects)...

Comment: are u sure that all content type changes are also visible in the shopping cart view ?

Comment: if you use themer it will, for views you can attach relations and so on